# How can i convert specific tag to jsx element in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, string, api, jsx

I have an API data ehich is a string contains many html tag.plaese help me how can i convert this string from API to JSX and can use specific tag as JSX element.

I don't want use dangerouslyInnerHTML.suggest me another way

Mydata:'

some paragraph

.this is strong</strong'

I want:

some paragraph

in react

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

React.createElement(component, props, ...children) function. The JSX code:

Click Me

compiles into:

React.createElement(
MyButton,
{color: 'blue', shadowSize: 2},
'Click Me'
)
You can also use the self-closing form of the tag if there are no children. So:

compiles into:

React.createElement(
'div',
{className: 'sidebar'}
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).